# VBA Excel - Search rows for string and if found copy entire cell to a specific location

Tags: excel, vba

I got 3000 rows of data in Excel.
Each row contains the same type of information but not in the right order.
What i need to do is to gather the same type of information under the same column.I would like to create a macro that is going to:

- Search a row for a partial string (some values have similar strings but fall under different categories)
- If the string is part of a cell copy the entire cell in a
  new location
- Repeat for the next row

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, write your attempt code, then ask help to repair it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub MoveColumns()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rFind As Range
Dim r As String
Dim m As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
MsgBox (LastRow)
For n = 1 To LastRow
    r = n & ":" & n
    Range(r).Select
    With Range(r)
        Set rFind = .Find(What:="Spain*", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            If rFind.Column < 6 Then
                m = 6 - rFind.Column
                Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, m)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            ElseIf rFind.Column > 6 Then
                m = rFind.Column - 6
                Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, m)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATED**
If row doesn't contain any value starts with "Spain", this row is simply ignored and skipped.
I hope you can modify and customize the way suitable for your data.

Comment: What if i got information like "Spain_1:10" and "Spain_2:20" where Spain_1 and Spain_2 belong to different columns?

Comment: You should find key column value which exists in every row (in my example "Spain"). This key value can be differs from other values with suffix or prefix, so you should modify code. For example, if "Spain1" and "Spain2" are key values, this can be `.Find(What:="Spain*"`

Comment: Good so far but the script doesn't leave blank the cells of the rows in which neither Spain_1 or Spain_2 was not present. Instead it reproduces the last valid value until it finds a new one.

Comment: @DimmForSiege, provide examples of "before" and "after" scenarios instead of having people guessing at what could ever be your data structure.

Comment: The data structure is similar to the one presented above.

Comment: The difference is that the string "Spain" is missing in some of my rows. This particular script wont leave empty the rows where is the string "Spain" is missing instead it will keep placing the word "Spain" although it shouldn't.

Comment: If so,  just add `ElseIf rFind is Nothing Then Continue`

Comment: Please check the changes I made above. Something is wrong.

Comment: I am more than grateful. Thank you so much